# How to avoid path or directories manipulation in the file upload function?

Tags: c#, asp.net, security

In the file upload function that I am working on it, one important issue is to have the path where I can save the image user uploaded. In the following code, I already specified the folder within the web-based application folder for saving the uploaded files. My instructor told me that I still have a security hole with these following lines in the code-behind of asp.net UploadFile control and I don't know why!!!

```
string path = @"~\Images\"; 
string comPath = Server.MapPath(path + "\\" + FileUpload1.FileName);
```

**Could you please tell me how to prevent this kind of security hole?**

**UPDATE:**

Could anyone tell me how to avoid this kind of security hole? I am still trying to find something to make these two lines secure.

Comment: One thing you could do is to use Path.Combine. (That's not related to your security hole question though, but its a good practice)

Comment: Here's an article I found regarding this, if someone's still looking https://blog.mindedsecurity.com/2018/10/how-to-prevent-path-traversal-in-net.html?m=1

Answer (score 1):

> My instructor told me that I still have a security hole with these following lines in the code-behind of asp.net UploadFile control and I don't know why!!!

Imagine what would happen if the client send something like `..\..\foo.jpg` as file name.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying the reason. So how can I prevent this hole?

Comment: Well, if `Server.MapPath` resolves paths like `~\Images\..\foo\image.jpg` to `~\foo\image.jpg`, you could check if the prefix of the resulting path is still `~\Images\` – and if not reject it. Or you extract just the file name if the client sends a whole path. You should not trust a file name coming from the client anyway – it could contain other characters that prove problematic in the file system, f.e. a `?` or `*`. If not necessary, you should not use the file name that the client send at all, but make up your own (random, uniqid, …) and save the “translation” of new to original file name.

Comment: Thank you very much for your explanation. You clarified many things to me. Could you please give me a code snippet about how to check the prefix of the resulting path with `Server.MapPath`. Thanks a lot again for your help.

Answer (score 0):

A fairly simple fix is to make sure the file name has no `\` or `/` characters in it, by stripping away everything up to the first such character.  (This is a good idea anyway, since browsers vary in their treatment of upload file names: some will [send the full path](http://www.cs.tut.fi/~jkorpela/forms/file.html#name), some [just the plain file name](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=143220) and some may even [send a fake path instead](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ie/archive/2009/03/20/rtm-platform-changes.aspx).)

The easy way to do this is with a Regex:

```
string fileName = Regex.Replace( FileUpload1.FileName, @"(?s)^.*[\\/]", "" );
```

Note that, depending on your OS and file system, there are other characters that could potentially cause problems as well.  The safest option, in general, is to strip away *all* characters except those you *know* are safe, something like this:

```
string safeFileName = Regex.Replace( fileName, @"[^A-Za-z0-9\-._() ]", "" );
```

You may also want to further ensure that the file name has an extension that matches the type you expect the file to have.